# Trying to grab links from a url to TextView

Tags: android

I would like to just get the links from a url to display either on a TextView or WebView if that could work. I tried pulling in the data with JSON, but I end up with something like this

```
b>Dog/b -Wikipedia,the free encyclopedia
en.wikipedia.org
<Dog/b>Health Center |b>Dog /b
```

-Which I could work with if I could get the `<b>`'s out of there. Any guidance would be appreciated, only about 3 months into programming.

Comment: Did you copy and paste this result or did you type it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this : `<a href='http://www.wikipedia.org/'>Wikipedia,the free encyclopedia</a>`